# How to call JavaScript on change of CSS

Tags: javascript, css, tinyscrollbar

I'm using [tinyscrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar) to show some text in a box. I have 2 stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 1152px) and (max-width: 9000px)" href="grid-1218.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 1151px)" href="grid-978.css"/>
```

I face a problem: when I change CSS the box gets bigger but the height stays the same and I don't want to declare height in CSS as i got some more boxes.

Is there any way to rerun the script to get new height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a specific event for media query changes, as far as I know.

You can bind to the window's `resize` event and re-run your javascript on every resize, or do some checking to see whether a resize is an important one.

Comment: found this oScrollbar5.tinyscrollbar_update(); to update content can you send me the full script for that on resize ?

Comment: `window.onresize = function() { oScrollbar5.tinyscrollbar_update(); }`  although personally I get bored quite quickly of setting up event handlers manually and always use jQuery to make it more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

It's accepted so just for the record. You can also use `matchMedia` and `addListener`:

```
window.matchMedia("(min-width: 152px) and (max-width: 900px)").addListener(function(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) {
        oScrollbar5.tinyscrollbar_update();
    }
});
```

It works in IE10+, so sure for now `window.onresize` is better.